# combine multiple audio files with slience between each audio file in sox

Tags: command-line, wav, sox

I have about 20 audio files(.wav) in a folder , this is how I combine this wave files

```
sox *.wav output.wav
```

I want to add delay or silence between each wave .

I have tried `pad` , but it's just put the silence only at the start and end of `output.wav` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to insert a silent track *between* each track as you specify them so you end up with something like:

```
sox track1.wav silence.wav track2.wav silence.wav ... output.wav
```

You can do that manually (as above), or we can loop the current directory with an inline for-loop. Something like this should work:

```
sox -n -r 44100 -c 2 /tmp/silence.wav trim 0.0 2
sox $(for f in *.wav; do echo -n "$f /tmp/silence.wav "; done) output.wav
```

The silence-generator is [stolen from here](http://activearchives.org/wiki/Padding_an_audio_file_with_silence_using_sox).

Comment: Sry friend seems same solution in same time, lol, same stolen

Comment: script with `loop` works :) Thanks a lot

Comment: When the number of `trackN.wav` is very large (e.g. `1000`), `Too many open files` error occurs because `sox` tries to open `silence.wav` the number of times specified as command-line arguments. To avoid this, you can generate multiple silent files (i.e. `silence_1.wav`, `silence_2.wav`, ...) and iteratively or randomly use them (e.g. `/tmp/silence_$((RANDOM % 10)).wav`).

Answer (score 4):

Generate 2 seconds of (stereo) silence

```
sox -n -r 44100 -c 2 silence.wav trim 0.0 3.0
```

Combining the files

```
sox silence.wav filetopad.mp3 silence.wav output.wav
```

source http://activearchives.org/wiki/Padding_an_audio_file_with_silence_using_sox

#### Another possible solution

quoted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587135/sox-merge-two-audio-files-with-a-pad

```
sox starts-last.mp3 -p pad 2 0 | sox - -m starts-second.mp3 -p pad 2 0 | sox - -m starts-first.mp3 combined.mp3
```